# How can I get a array as an input value inserted into an HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've been on this all day.

**HTML Code**

```
    <label>Input values</label>
    <input type="text" id="arrays" placeholder="Enter Array" >
    <button id="objectify" type= "button">Click</button>

    <div id="results"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var input= document.getElementById('arrays').value; //["book", 3, "pin", 4];//
var btn = document.getElementById('objectify');
var output = document.getElementById('results');


function objectifyArr(x) {
    var myObject = {
        String: [],
        Number: []
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (typeof x[i] === 'string' || x[i] instanceof String){
            myObject.String.push(x[i]); 
        } else if (typeof x[i] === 'number' || x[i] instanceof Number){
            myObject.Number.push(x[i]);
        }
    }
    return myObject;
}
btn.onclick = function () {
    output.textContent = JSON.stringify(objectifyArr(inputValue));

}
```

The code seems to work when I assign 'inputValue' a range of array values but doesn't when I get the array via getElementbyId.value. Is there an input type for arrays specifically or did I assign the wrong value to my variable?

Regardless of what the mistake is, I'll be glad if someone pointed it out for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "an array as an input value"?  A string with comma-separated values?

Comment: It would also help to know a bit about what you're trying to do.  It looks like you're building a JSON parser by hand...

Comment: The code is supposed to take an array as an input value and return an object. For example, the user puts in [1, ’hi’, 2.8 , 'hello'] and the code returns { String: ['hi', 'hello'] , Number [1, 2.8] }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and waiting to get the `value` of the `input` until you actually click the button?

Also (FYI), `label` requires that you either nest the element that it is a label for within it or that you add the `for` attribute and give it the value of the `id` of the element that it is a `label` "for".

```js
var input= document.getElementById('arrays'); //["book", 3, "pin", 4];//
var btn = document.getElementById('objectify');
var output = document.getElementById('results');

btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  let myArray = JSON.parse(input.value);
  output.textContent = myArray;
  console.log(myArray);
});
```

```html
<label for="arrays">Input values</label>
<input id="arrays" placeholder="Enter Array" value='["book", 3, "pin", 4]'>
<button id="objectify" type= "button">Click</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. How do we make the value attribute equal to the array the user puts into the input field? Without assigning it in the HTML form?

Comment: @Nabeelah The code already does that with: `let myArray = JSON.parse(input.value);`. I only hard-coded the array into the input (with the HTML `value='["book", 3, "pin", 4]'`) so you wouldn't have to type it for this test. Just remove that HTML and the code will still work, it just won't have anything pre-filled into the text box.

Comment: Hi @Scott. Just re-read your tip and it really helped me out. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you declare this in the top of your JS file:

```
var input= document.getElementById('arrays').value
```

This is literally saying "assign the **current** value of the element to my *input* variable". Obviously, the input element at the start of the script is empty, therefore the value is `''`.

After that, the other problem is that as your input only accepts *text*, all the characters inside will be `String` type, so looping and checking for the `typeof` of each character will always yield it as a `String`.
A workaround for that would be using a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

[Here's a working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g208ebz3/1/)

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I always thought it was supposed to get the value the user entered.